# Painful to read commented code in terminal emacs [Linux Mint]

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, emacs, display

I just started using linux mint and it's fairly good but the default terminal e-macs mode has painful to read commented code as well as strings for c++ (text enclosed in either /* */, " ", // ).

My system is an xps 13 using Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon.  Here is an example which may or may not display on some systems

[image]

How can this extreme contrast be changed without changing much else about the terminal?

Comment: Related question: [Change Emacs syntax highlighting colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1076503/change-emacs-syntax-highlighting-colors)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @ErikF for showing me the related question.  One can change the color by doing the following steps.  Go to a cpp file and put the cursor on a comment.  Hit the command:

```
M-x customize-face
```

You should see `Customize face (default font-lock-comment-face'):` , hit enter.

You then should get a new screen. Maneuver the cursor to "choose" in the line `[X] Foreground: color-63   [ Choose ]  (sample)` (the color will be different).

A dropdown will appear with the various colors,  pick the one you want.  Afterward maneuver the cursor to "Apply and Save", hit enter and you are all set.  I didn't change the "string" color because I liked the way it looked after the change but it should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using vim.

Vim also has syntax highlighting, and you have a few easy options if you dislike the current display

```
:set bg dark
:set bg light
```

Above depending on your terminal background.

```
:syntax on
```

To turn on syntax highlighting

To change the display colour scheme, you can use the :colo command.

My favourite is "ron":-

```
:colo ron
:colo <ctrl-d> will show all the available schemes, e.g. "ron", "pablo", "peachpuff"...
```

Hope that helps.